# looping through elements in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got a page with bunch of drop downs and each drop down has a button next to it. When the page initially loads I want all the buttons to be disabled and if there is a change to a specific drop down then its corresponding button shall be enabled.

I've got the following code down for this but I need to know how to loop through all the drop downs and buttons so I can generalize it.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  //disable all buttons
  function disableAllButtons () {
      $(':input[type=button]').attr("disabled", "true");
  }
  disableAllButtons();
  //enable button when drop down changes
  $(':input[name=sNewPKvalue1]').focus(function() {
      disableAllButtons();
      $(':input[name=Update0]').removeAttr("disabled");
  })
  //enable button when drop down changes
  $(':input[name=sNewPKvalue2]').focus(function() {
      disableAllButtons();
      $(':input[name=Update1]').removeAttr("disabled");
  })
  ////.....question?
});
```

**Question**

If I have 12 dropdowns and 12 buttons

How do I loop through all the drop downs with name `sNewPKvalue[1-12]` and all the buttons with name `Update[0-11]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it that way.

```
for (var i = 0; i < 12; i++)
{
  $(':input[name=sNewPKvalue'+(i+1)+']').focus(function() {
      disableAllButtons();
      $(':input[name=Update'+i+']').removeAttr("disabled");
  })
}
```

Or

```
  $(':input[name^=sNewPKvalue]').focus(function() {
      disableAllButtons();
      $(':input[name=Update'+(Number(this.name.match(/[0-9]+/))-1)+']').removeAttr("disabled");
  })
```

Comment: I tried the loop but it always removes disabled attribute from the last update button. it does not sync with the drop down. I think that is because on each focus it is going through the loop. the second approach works much better

Answer (score 2):

I would not recommend a loop.  Just use a selector that selects the elements you want and perform the appropriate action.  My first thought is to assign a CSS class to the buttons and drop down lists you are talking about.  Then you can simply do something like this:

```
$('.dropDown').focus(function(){
   $(".ddlButton").attr("disabled", "true");
   $(this).closest('.ddlButton').removeAttr("disabled");
});
```

Comment: the `.closest()` won't work since it applies only to DOM tree. In my case the `input[type=button]` is not in a DOM tree under the dropdown

Comment: Can you post your HTML or better yet a fiddle with the HTML in it?

Comment: I've posted an example here http://jsbin.com/afiwag the source code for JS shows your approach. From reading the `.closest()` documentation I think it would only work in a DOM tree http://api.jquery.com/closest/

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like:

```
$.each([1, 12], function(index, value) {
    var valmin = val - 1;
    $(':input[name=sNewPKvalue'+value+']').focus(function() {
        disableAllButtons();
        $(':input[name=Update'+valmin+']').removeAttr("disabled");
    })
});
```

I didn't test this one, but you should get the idea ;)

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is to make a for loop.

```
for(var i = 1; i <= 12; i++) {
    $("select[name='sNewPKvalue"+i+"']").doSomething();
}

for(var i = 1; i <= 11; i++) {
    $(":button[name='Update"+i+"']").doSomething();
}
```